# Unable to load redis module, RedisJSON

Tags: linux, rust, redis, rust-cargo, redisjson

After following the instructions specified [here](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/#download-and-running-binaries) to compile the source code of RedisJson, got the rejson.so file at project_root/target/release, then I entered this command sudo redis-server --loadmodule /home/username/RedisJSON/target/release/rejson.so to load redis module. But I got this error message.

```
Server initialized
7666:M 14 Sep 2021 13:27:38.795 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
7666:M 14 Sep 2021 13:27:38.795 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
7666:M 14 Sep 2021 13:27:38.862 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V1 API
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/redis-module-0.23.0/src/raw.rs:580:42
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
Aborted
```

How can I get this fixed, please?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [#175](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redismodule-rs/issues/175) (though that's not helpful given that it's not had any response); both cases are missing the binding to the [`RedisModule_ExportSharedAPI`](https://redis.io/topics/modules-api-ref#RedisModule_ExportSharedAPI) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedisJSON requires Redis 6+, it seems like you're running on an older version of Redis.